# Difference between single quotes and double quotes

Tags: linux, shell

I have two variables declared in shell script

```
var1=23
var2=27

echo $var1              # Prints 23
echo '$var1'            # Prints $var1
echo "$var1"            # Prints 23
```

From the above I have some confusion regarding single and double quotes usage on variables.

please can any one clarify this with an example difference between single and double quote.

Comment: What's the confusion? What did you expect to be printed?

Comment: Iam not getting difference between single and double quotes in the above context . In the above without using quotes it printed 23, with double quotes it printed 23 ,then with single quote it printed as it is. why is that?

Comment: Start here.  http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/SpecialCharacters

Comment: If you're asking something covered by preexisting questions, it's helpful to describe *how your question differs* -- that is to say, what you understood those preexisting questions' answers to mean, and what specific points of confusion you still have after reading them.

Comment: Or here: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quoting.html#Quoting